# Any way to set up FlexUnit in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, unit-testing

I'm using Eclipse 4.2.1 (Juno), and also set up CFEclipse with MX Unit.  I am working with the Flex SDK (various versions from 3.5.0 and up), and I'm using an ant script to build my projects.  At this point, I have a flex project built and running, and MXUnit is also working on the ColdFusion components.

I'd like to set up FlexUnit, but in my searching, I can't find any way to get it set up (since there is no FlexBuilder/FlashBuilder plugin for eclipse anymore).  I found at plugin at www.codesquared.com/eclipse, but when I tried downloading/installing it, I got an error because I don't have FlashBuilder installed.

Has anyone here set this up with only Eclipse?

Thanks!

Comment: `since there is no FlexBuilder/FlashBuilder plugin for eclipse anymore`??? Adobe just released version 4.7

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear. Yes, there is a FlashBuilder plugin, but its not free, and the SDK is.

Comment: You can use FlexUnit standalone, or through a build tool (ANT, Maven, Gradle, ...). But if you want IDE integration, I don't think there's a separate plugin that integrates FlexUnit only. Wouldn't make much sense to me either: either you're the Flex developer and you have an IDE, or you're not and then the build tools take care of the testing for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flex development on Linux, what's a good free environment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200219/flex-development-on-linux-whats-a-good-free-environment)